# Difference between $S^{1}$ and $\mathbb{S}^{1}$

Tags: general-topology, notation

Whats the difference between the two? Or are they both the unit circle? My lecture notes for a topology course use $S^{1}$ for the "circle" in one example and $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ in the next example for the "boundary circle". Is it just a notational inconsistency?

EDIT: Neither is defined in the notes. I infer that the "boundary circle" is $\{x^{2} + y^{2} = 1 \mid x, y \in  $$\mathbb{R}$$\}$ from the example. Indeed, $S^{1}$ seemingly denotes the same thing.

Comment: What exactly is the boundary circle?

Comment: Yes, these are the same.

Comment: In general, the notation $S^1$ or $\mathbb{S}^1$ could mean just about anything.  In the context of a topology class, both notations almost certainly mean a circle (i.e. the one-dimensional boundary of a two-dimensional disk).  However, as this notation is appearing in your lecture notes rather than in some published text, it is likely impossible for us to give a definite answer here.  You should consult with your lecturer.  I am voting to close this question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Nice profile pic :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are both used to mean the circle. Probably the non-blackboard-bold one is the more common.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I expected, but just wanted to clarify.